# Code doesn't work on IE6 if i click a button to open a popup form

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-6

my code is working perfectly on firefox but not on IExplorer 6
some part of my code is:

```
document.getElementById('layout').style.opacity = .7
document.getElementById('layout').style.display = "block"
```

Comment: The solution to your problem is dropping support for IE6. It's not worth the effort for the [less than 0.3%](http://caniuse.com/usage_table.php) of users.

Comment: @Joeytje50 even if you are right, it is not helping.
OP: what is your question?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity -- opacity only works in ie9+

Comment: @Markus which is why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: just noticed the note: `Transparency for elements in IE8 and older can be achieved using the proprietary "filter" property and does not work well with PNG images using alpha transparency.` -- see @sjkm's answer.

Comment: If the jQuery library is attached then it should be used.

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' sometimes people don't have the luxury of choosing what browsers they do or don't want to support. sometimes your client/customer is on ie6 and they have their reasons why and you have to support it period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to get browser at first by writing javascript code

```
var browser=navigator.appName //get Browser name
```

and then set the opacity for different browsers

```
if(browser=="Netscape")  //For mozilla firefox
{
document.getElementById('layout').style.opacity = .7;   
}

if(browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
document.getElementById('layout').style.filter:alpha(opacity=70); /* IE 5-7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
}
```

You can visit my blog for more reference http://cshotopics.blogspot.in/2014/02/interactive-form-design-using-css-jquery.html

Comment: although your answer is good.. but this code is considerable too..                                                                 document.getElementById("layout").className = "transparent_class";

with css

.transparent_class {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
 
  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
 
  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.7;
 
  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
 
  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.7;
}

Answer (score 4):

this should work in IE 6:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=70);
```

However, as already mentioned you should only support IE 6 if you really have to.

**Update**

Like Joeytje50 writes, you could also additionally add the `-ms-filter` attribute:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
```

The `filter` attribute is for all IE versions whereas `-ms-filter` is supported in IE8+

> > **Taken from msdn.microsoft.com:**
> >     The -ms-filter attribute is an extension to CSS, and can be used as a
> >     synonym for filter in IE8 Standards mode. When you use -ms-filter,
> >     enclose the progid in single quotes (') or double quotes ("). Use
> >     commas (,) to separate multiple values.

Comment: According to http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/ you also need `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";` for IE8

Comment: I believe you also need to *have layout* by including a property such as `zoom: 1`.